# Automatic send Sms basis on date

Tags: android

I am developing one android application  which would be able to get stored date of my applications database and check this date with current date, if matched then automatically send some SMS to the person .But I don't know how to do this. please help.in database one table is present which has some entities like person name, mobile no,date,message.help !!

Comment: You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: yes but i want to store person name and his birthdate to database and then check current date with stored date so how to do this

Comment: u want some hint or complete source code, coz u need to create one alarm manager tht would check database nd once the date wil match thn it would send sms

Comment: if you give full source then it will better to understand. so can you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PendingIntent and AlarmManager to achieve this. Take a look at it.

First Initialize alarmManager ans PendingIntent.

```
    intentsOpen = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intentsOpen.setAction("com.sandeep.alarm.ACTION");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,111, intentsOpen, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

set date and time on which you want to send sms.

```
 //set what you want only. I am giving all
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
 // set action 
                intentsOpen.setAction("com.sandeep.sendsms.ACTION");
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,112, intentsOpen, 0);
                if((calendar.getTimeInMillis() > System.currentTimeMillis())){
 // Always use this if condition so your receiver will not trigger when you start app. if triggerAtMillis is older than the currentMillis, the alarm will be fired no matter when you set it
 // to send sms on repetitive basis
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
 // 24*60*60*1000 is a duration means how much day you want to repeat. 

// to send sms once only
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent)
   }
```

Here is Alarm Receiver Class.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String SEND_SMS = "com.sandeep.sendsms.ACTION";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (SEND_SMS .equals(action)) {
        // HERE you can code to send sms.

    }

}
```

}